# import csv data into mysql via python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to insert csv data in a mysql db using the following code.

```
import mysql.connector
import csv

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="***",
    database="celldb"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "DROP TABLE enodeb"
mycursor.execute(sql)

mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE enodeb (id int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, enodeb_id VARCHAR(255), enodeb_name VARCHAR(255), cabinet_type VARCHAR(255), du_type VARCHAR(2505), mcc int(3), mnc int(3), ne_type VARCHAR(255), oam_ip VARCHAR(255), s1_ip VARCHAR(25005), nw_type VARCHAR(255))")


with open('site_details.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    next(csvreader)
    for row in csvreader:
        print (row)
        mycursor.execute('INSERT INTO enodeb(enodeb_id, enodeb_name, cabinet_type, du_type, mcc, mnc, ne_type, oam_ip, s1_ip, nw_type)' 'VALUES(%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s)',row)
```

My CSV file looks like this -

```
enodeb_id,enodeb_name,cabinet_type,du_type,mcc,mnc,ne_type,oam_ip,s1_ip,nw_type
936233,936233_LITTLE_STURGEON,RBS 6201,DUS3102,311,850,ERBS,173.254.129.189,2001:4888:2e30:1100:0343:0411:0000:0000,OMS
```

When I run this code I get the following error -

```
celldb@lteadmin:~/celldb/python_enb_dump/my_sql_update$ python db_connect.py  
['936233', '936233_LITTLE_STURGEON', 'RBS 6201', 'DUS3102', '311', '850', 'ERBS', '173.254.129.189', '2001:4888:2e30:1100:0343:0411:0000:0000', 'OMS']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db_connect.py", line 26, in <module>
    mycursor.execute('INSERT INTO enodeb(enodeb_id, enodeb_name, cabinet_type, du_type, mcc, mnc, ne_type, oam_ip, s1_ip, nw_type)' 'VALUES(%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s)',row)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 569, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 553, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 442, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Please advise what I am missing.

Comment: You are missing commas between the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a space between your insert statement and Values statements. Also your Values should be comma separated based on the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html).

Another thing I think is necessary for this to work is that row is a tuple.

It should be:

```
mycursor.execute('INSERT INTO enodeb (enodeb_id, enodeb_name, cabinet_type, du_type, mcc, mnc, ne_type, oam_ip, s1_ip, nw_type) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)', tuple(row))
```